# "more" button in a list responsive as angular directive in .jade and .cofee

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, coffeescript, pug

I need to do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/860LzgLL/) but as an AngularJS directive and using .jade and .coffee. I am quite new to the last ones, so I don't how can I achieve that.

```
var elemWidth, fitCount, fixedWidth = 120,  
    $menu = $("ul#menu"), $collectedSet;

collect();
$(window).resize(collect);

function collect() {
    elemWidth = $menu.width();
    fitCount = Math.floor(elemWidth / fixedWidth) - 1;
    $collectedSet = $menu.children(":gt(" + fitCount + ")");
    $("#submenu").empty().append($collectedSet.clone());    
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: So you want the above code to be translated to coffee and included in a jade template?

Comment: @SaschaKluth thanks for answering! Yep, and I would like it to be an angular directive...

Answer (score 0):

Your cs would be

```
elemWidth = undefined
fitCount = undefined
fixedWidth = 120
$menu = $('ul#menu')
$collectedSet = undefined

collect = ->
  elemWidth = $menu.width()
  fitCount = Math.floor(elemWidth / fixedWidth) - 1
  $collectedSet = $menu.children(':gt(' + fitCount + ')')
  $('#submenu').empty().append $collectedSet.clone()
  return

collect()
$(window).resize collect
```

So a jade template could be

```
script
  :coffee-script
    elemWidth = undefined
    fitCount = undefined
    fixedWidth = 120
    $menu = $('ul#menu')
    $collectedSet = undefined

    collect = ->
      elemWidth = $menu.width()
      fitCount = Math.floor(elemWidth / fixedWidth) - 1
      $collectedSet = $menu.children(':gt(' + fitCount + ')')
      $('#submenu').empty().append $collectedSet.clone()
      return

    collect()
    $(window).resize collect
```

A directive could be

```
app.directive 'hello', ->
    class Habit
        constructor: ->
            restict: 'E'
            template: '../_template/_formTemplate/generated_from_jade_template.html'
```

Something like that? (I did not look at the content of your fiddle 'cause it did not work in my browser)